# Conditional Include on Items in an Item Group

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I want to copy files over to a server but before i do this i would like to include the latest msi file that i generate.

I noticed that the ItemGroup and Item have a Condition attribute but i do not know how to utilize this to include the latest file.

So far this is my setup:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
 <ItemGroup>
  <Installers Include="\\SERVERNAME\BuildOutput\ProductStream\**\Installers\Customer\Installer.msi"/>
</ItemGroup>
<Message Text="FirstItem: %(Installers.Filename)" />
<Message Text="FirstItem: %(Installers.FullPath)" />
```

The output of this are two files:
e.g

```
\\Servername\BuildOutput\ProductStream\Installers\ProductStreamV2.1.1202.1402\Installer.msi
\\Servername\BuildOutput\ProductStream\Installers\ProductStreamV2.1.1405.1301\Installer.msi
```

I want to include the 2.1.1405.1301 build in the Item as this is the latest one.

I would appreciate if someone would assist me  because i cannot find how to go about doing this from the MSDN blogs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom task for this purpose. It allows you to filter items any way you want. Here I used regular expressions to select the latest installer:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
         <Installers Include="**\Installer.msi"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <SelectLatestInstaller Installers="@(Installers)">
        <Output TaskParameter="LatestInstaller" ItemName="LatestInstaller" />
    </SelectLatestInstaller>
    <Message Text="%(LatestInstaller.FullPath)" />
</Target>

<UsingTask TaskName="SelectLatestInstaller" 
           TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" 
           AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
        <Installers ParameterType="System.String[]" Required="true" />
        <LatestInstaller ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
        <Reference Include="System.Linq" />
        <Using Namespace="System" />
        <Using Namespace="System.Linq" />
        <Using Namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
        <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
            <![CDATA[
                LatestInstaller = Installers
                    .OrderByDescending(f => Regex.Match(f, @"\\ProductStreamV(?<version>(\d+.){0,3}\d+)\\").Groups["version"].Value)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
        ]]>
        </Code>
    </Task>
</UsingTask>
```